# at com.example.u.locationtracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I am new on android and working on my android app's login activity for which em using php mysql with volley library. But every time I run my app on emulator it shows the message Unfortunately, app has stopped. Here the login activity code is:

```
package com.example.u.locationtracker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText pass1, email1;
    private Button login;
    private TextView link_reg;
    private ProgressBar loading;
    private String URL_LOGIN= "http://192.168.1.1/register.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        email1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail1);
        pass1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassl);

        loading= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading1);

        link_reg= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup);

        login= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mEmail= email1.getText().toString().trim();
                String mpass= pass1.getText().toString().trim();

                if(!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mpass.isEmpty()){
                    Login(mEmail, mpass);
                }else{
                    email1.setError("Please Enter Email...!");
                    pass1.setError("Please Enter Password...!");
                }
            }
        });

        link_reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });

    }

    private void Login(final String email, final String pass) {
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
                            String success= jsonObject.getString("Success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("Login");

                            if(success.equals("1")){
                                for (int i= 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject object= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Toast t= Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                            "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    t.show();

                                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast t1= Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Error" + e.toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            t1.show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast t2= Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Error" + error.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        t2.show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params= new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Email", email);
                params.put("Password", pass);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

According to logcat the problem is:
at com.example.u.locationtracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)

here the php code:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $email= $_POST['email1'];
    $pass= $_POST['pass1'];

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $select= "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE Email= '$email' ";

    $r= mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    $result= array();
    $result['login']= array();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($r)=== 1) {
        $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

        if ( password_verify($pass, $row['Pass']) ) {
            $index['Name']= $row['Name'];
            $index['Email']= $row['Email'];

            array_push($result['login'], $index);
            $result['success']= "1";
            $result['message']= "Success";
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysql_close($conn);
        }else{
            $result['success']= "0";
            $result['message']= "Error";
            echo json_encode($result);
            mysql_close($conn);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
02-03 21:03:21.626 2006-2012/? E/jdwp: Failed writing handshake bytes: Broken pipe (-1 of 14)
02-03 21:03:21.806 2006-2006/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
02-03 21:03:21.806 2006-2006/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
02-03 21:03:21.826 2006-2006/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets
02-03 21:03:21.826 2006-2006/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
02-03 21:03:21.836 2006-2006/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
02-03 21:03:22.756 2006-2006/com.example.u.locationtracker E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
02-03 21:03:27.786 2006-2006/com.example.u.locationtracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.u.locationtracker, PID: 2006
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.u.locationtracker/com.example.u.locationtracker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.u.locationtracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07005d a=-1 r=0x7f07005d}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.u.locationtracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you add the activity xml too? error logs suggests that there is some error in your layout itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to lie in this line:
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Are you sure, the layout exists and doesn't have compile errors?

A full stacktrace would be more helpful

Comment: I've added the logcat to my question.... please give me a suggestion to sort it out.

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07005d a=-1 r=0x7f07005d}
It seems like, you create an ImageView in your layout, but pass a non-drawable resource in it

Comment: Very nice to hear! Glad, I could help